# unable to implement filters in laravel query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to create a view to display applications for specific jobs. So far, my code outputs all jobs and is unable to output applications for specific jobs. I want to be able to view applications for a specific job and NOT all jobs at the same time. So if I publish an opening for a race car driver, I want to be able to view applications for only this "race car driver" slot. So far, my code just outputs all jobs at once.

```php
public function viewapplications($id){

$user = auth()->user()->id;
$users = DB::table('users')
->join('jobs', 'jobs.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
->join('job_applications', 'job_applications.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
->where('users.id', '=', $user, 'AND', 'jobs.id', '=', 'job_applications.job_id')
->get();

return view('jobs.viewapplications', compact('users'));
}
```

Comment: get the raw query and see where it urgs, you shouled only become jobs for the one user and on apllicationid

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your query returns records for all users with jobs and job_application, since you have table users as a starting point and you're joining other 2 tables.

What you need to do is to start from jobs table, if that's what you want to see, and join the remaining tables to get what you need:

```
DB::table('jobs')
            ->join('job_applications', 'jobs.id', '=','job_applications.job_id')
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'job_applications.user_id')
            ->get();
```

Comment: Hi NL,  your code returns no results at all.